# How to Print Stack Panel to a4 paper size in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, printing

I am stuck in my project. My WPF application is a text editor application. It contains various stackpanels. Each stack panel has multiple textblocks. Each stack panel has width 500 and height 800.

I need to provide a print functionality. When ever user clicks on print button, each stack panel should print to each a4 size paper.

Note: Each textblock in the stack panel are formatted texts. So can not use e.graphics.drawString. Because I need to maintain exactly each stack panel look in each printed page.

Please guide me how could I print each stack panel to a4 paper size? Please look into the following image. The white portion are stack panel. Currently it has 25 stack panel. So when I print, the PDF file should contain 25 pages and each page should look exactly each stack panel in the application. Sorry for asking such big help. I have been struggling since very very long time to figure out. Any guidance, any help would be truly welcome. Thanks in Advance.

The code which I am using is:

```
private void PrintDocument() {
            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            foreach (StackPanel spnl in rootStackPanel.Children) {
                pd.PrintVisual(spnl,"Printing..");
            }

        }
```

Problem with this code, it prints each stackpanel in individual PDF File!!

[Please look into the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb50b.png)

Comment: what is your achievement so far, share your code

Comment: Hi Usman Ali. Thanks For your response. Please look in my post. I have added the code.